# Wordpress Elementor custom query with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I'm not familiar with PHP but tried to insert a code snippet in theme/functions.php. My purpose is querying some posts base on Event custom post type and a custom field.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/events', function( $query ) {
  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                  'key' => 'dstart',
                  'type' => 'DATE',
                  'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                  'compare' => '>'            
              ),
            ),         
  );
$query->set($args);
} );
```

But it has an error like this:

```
Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Query::set(), 1 passed in wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/functions.php on line 46 and exactly 2 expected in wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:1752
Stack trace:
#0 wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/functions.php(46): WP_Query->set(Array)
#1 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(294): {closure}(Object(WP_Query))
#2 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#3 wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/query-control/classes/elementor-post-query.php(373): do_action('elementor/query...', Object(WP_Query), Object(ElementorPro\Modules\Posts\Widgets\Posts))
#5 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): ElementorPro\Modules\QueryControl\Classes\Elementor_Post_Query->pre_get_posts_query_filter(Object(WP_Query))
#6 /var/www/
```

Can I know which parts I misunderstood? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/event', function( $query ) {
    // Here we set the query to fetch posts with
    // post type of 'custom-post-type1' and 'custom-post-type2'
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'event' ] );
    
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'dstart',
        'type' => 'DATE',
        'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    
    
} );
```